# AngularJS Simple conditions in the Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm implementing notifications feature. In the service, i would GET request a URL that returns an array of notifications.

In the controller i would have to set a variable that stores a message string for each notification type. I'm very new to angular and Just wanted to know if my syntax and logic is correct.

```
/* Model + Controller */
// Assume wrapped in controller function

$scope.notifications = notifications=[
{id:1, type: 6},
{id:2, type: 3},
{id:3, type:4}]; 

$scope.display_message = function(){

    if ($scope.notifications.type == 1){

    $scope.notification_message = "some text";

    } else if ($scope.notifications.type == 2){

    $scope.notification_message = "some text";

    }

  //... for brevity

return $scope.notification_message

}


/* View */

<li ng-repeat={{notification in notifications}}>

    {{display_message()}}
</li>
```

Comment: No, your logic and syntax both are incorrect

Comment: would appreciate a sample code. thanks :) @Samir

Answer (score 1):

the logic is a little bit confusing, but i think you want to display the message for each, so you need to pass the notification each time.

```js
// Assume wrapped in controller function

$scope.notifications = notifications=[
{id:1, type: 6},
{id:2, type: 3},
{id:3, type:4}]; 

$scope.display_message = function(notification){

    if (notification.type === 1){

    $scope.notification_message = "some text";

    } else if (notification.type === 2){

    $scope.notification_message = "some text";

    }

  //... for brevity

return $scope.notification_message

}


/* View */
```

```html
<li ng-repeat="notification in notifications">

    {{display_message(notifcation)}}
</li>
```

also you don't need the `{{}}` in `ng-repeat`, also allways use `===` not `==`

Comment: ..but you do need quotes!!

Comment: yeah i added them i noticed after posting

Comment: I guess the is no need to populate the scope with $scope.notification_message, as you're executing in loop, it'll only store the last message.

Comment: @Indra you may be write but I'm not sure if he is using it somewhere else in the code and that is why i don't think it should be changed unless it is really needed, stuff like '===' and '{{}}'  they'll break your code and a source of endless bugs

Answer (score 1):

Here $scope.notifications is a array then how can you check $scope.notifications.type == 1 ?

You can try this:

```
 $scope.display_message = function(notification){
 var message ;
if (notification.type == 1){

message  = "some text";

} else if (notification.type == 2){

message  = "some text";

}
 return message;
}
```

And then

```
<li ng-repeat="notification in notifications">

{{display_message(notifcation)}}
</li>
```

Comment: also missing the quotes!